Incomplete Series Evaluation in Mathematica for Large Values of 
The evaluation of the series
Series[((1/2 + Sqrt[n])^3 n^(15))/(((7 Sqrt[2])/(3 n^(1/4)) +
 C1/n^(3/4) + n^(1/4))^(37)), {n, Infinity, 2}]

Does not complete where C1 is a constant.  Hours and no result.  However, if I remove the constant then the series
Series[((1/2 + Sqrt[n])^3 n^(15))/(((7 Sqrt[2])/(3 n^(1/4)) + n^(1/4))^(37)),
 {n, Infinity, 2}]

Completes in seconds.
What is going on and how do I fix this.  This is holding up calculation progress.
Using Mathematical 12.2

Workaround:
$Version
(*14.0.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)*)

(Series[((1/2 + Sqrt[n])^3 n^B)/(C1/n^(3/4) + (7 Sqrt[2])/(3 n^(1/4)) + n^(1/4))^A, {n, Infinity, 2}, Assumptions -> {A > 0, B > 0, C1 > 0}] // 
Normal) /. B -> 15 /. A -> 37 // FullSimplify // Expand

Asymptotic[((1/2 + Sqrt[n])^3  n^B)/(C1/n^(3/4) + (7  Sqrt[2])/(3  n^(1/4)) + n^(1/4))^A, {n, 
Infinity, 1}, Assumptions -> {A > 0, B > 0, C1 > 0}] /. 
B -> 15 /. A -> 37 // FullSimplify // Expand

In fact, I also don't know why Mathamatica chokes and calculate for long time.

Well, it is not clear as to why my original statement would not complete even after many hours, I tried your example and it completed in seconds.

Workaround:
f[n_] = ((1/2 + Sqrt[n])^3 n^15)/(C1/n^(3/4) + (7 Sqrt[2])/(3 n^(1/4)) + n^(1/4))^37;

Asymptotic[f[n], n -> ∞]
(*    n^(29/4) if C1 ∈ R    *)

Non-fractional expansion in terms of $m=\sqrt{n}$:
(Normal[Series[m^(-29/2) f[m^2], {m, ∞, 2}]] /.
    m -> Sqrt[n]) n^(29/4) // Expand

$$
-37 C_1 n^{25/4}+n^{29/4}-\frac{259}{3} \sqrt{2} n^{27/4}+\frac{3 n^{27/4}}{2}-\frac{259 n^{25/4}}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{275603 n^{25/4}}{36}
$$
